# Does intense, cyclically-pulsed light appear brighter than its average?

Tags: optics, visible-light, vision, perception

## Background

The Wikipedia article on the [Talbot-Plateau law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talbot-Plateau_law) mentions:

> If a light flickers so rapidly that it appears as continuous, then its perceived brightness will be determined by the relative periods of light and darkness: the longer the darkness, the weaker the light.

In an LED:

$$
I_{v} = I_{v}\left( @ k_{duty} = 1.0 \right)\ •\ k_{duty}
$$

where

- $ I_{v} $    : Light intensity $ [cd] $
- $ k_{duty} $ : Duty cycle $ [-] $, $ \left( 0 ≤ k_{duty} ≤ 1 \right) $

### Issue

The articles continues, however, that:

> In 1863, the experiments of A. Fick suggested that the Talbot-Plateau law does not hold for strong light intensities. This suggestion was later proven by O. Grünbaum in 1898 who demonstrated that **flickering strong light appears brighter than its steady state value**.

I am struggling to find more information on this latter portion.

The [Broca-Sulzer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broca-Sulzer_effect) was [mentioned](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/670219/led-perceived-light-intensity-greater-than-actual-light-intensity-via-weber-f?noredirect=1#comment1784503_670219) by user @periblepsis; however, this Wikipedia article makes no mention to A. Flick or O. Grünbaum and only applies to specific frequencies (peaking at roughly 10 [Hz]):

[image]

The Brücke-Bartley effect, also [mentioned](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/670219/led-perceived-light-intensity-greater-than-actual-light-intensity-via-weber-f?noredirect=1#comment1784503_670219) by user @periblepsis, is referenced [here][5]:

> The **Brücke-Bartley** effect is the phenomenon in which a flickering stimulus appears brighter than the same stimulus presented unflickering. There is a peak perceived flicker brightness at about 8 to 10 Hz (Bartley, 1939; Brücke, 1864).

Again, the peak is at levels far beneath the critical (discernable) flicker frequency for LED use, which is a minimum [2000 [Hz]](https://theconversation.com/the-scientific-reason-you-dont-like-led-bulbs-and-the-simple-way-to-fix-them-81639).

## Question

Are the intensities and frequencies which intense, cyclically-pulsed light appear brighter than its average those of contemporary LEDs pulsed at frequencies far above perceivable flicker, such that energy savings could be achieved by pulsing an LED rather than running it constantly?

[5]: [http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/User:Eugene_M._Izhikevich/Proposed/Flicker_fusion#:~:text=The%20Br%C3%BCcke-Bartley%20effect%20is,1939%3B%20Br%C3%BCcke%2C%201864](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/User:Eugene_M._Izhikevich/Proposed/Flicker_fusion#:%7E:text=The%20Br%C3%BCcke-Bartley%20effect%20is,1939%3B%20Br%C3%BCcke%2C%201864)).

Comment: That was before the invention of lasers. After their invention we can guarantee that strong pulses of light will not only not appear brighter, but absolutely everything you will see after such an experiment will appear much, much darker. So please be careful with modern light sources. I am not kidding. What they used to call "strong light" back then, is orders of magnitude less intense than a power LED or semiconductor laser for a few dollars is today. Before you do any experiments, I would strongly advise to check out the physical characteristics of those old light sources.

Comment: @FlatterMann : I want to run an indicator LED with a limited power source (battery). I wondered if pulsing the light would be more efficient $ \left[\frac{cd}{W}\right] $ — such as 10% duty cycle results in 10% light measured, but 15% light perceived by the eye. (If I understand the effect, I could optimize efficiency while still ensuring thresholds are met to prevent occular irritation, or worse: damage)

Comment: Even a 50% gain in brightness would be barely visible. What will be visible are strong, very short flashes at a low frequency (1Hz). If you need a truly low power indicator, use a different technology, like an LCD. That will give you many orders of magnitude in savings. In application in which permanence without power is required, they use eDisplays today. You can find those as price tags in many stores today.

Comment: By the way... light flickering at 10Hz can give seizures to some people... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosensitive_epilepsy. Even though it's only one in 4000 or so, that's a pretty solid reason not to use the technique. Just my two cents.

Comment: @FlatterMann : I was hoping the effect would apply to frequencies above the critical (discernable) flicker frequency ( $2000\ [Hz]$ )

Comment: Not so much according to your own source. Like I said, I wouldn't use the technique to begin with. It doesn't provide much upside as far as I can see.

Answer (score 4):

This has more to do with physiology of light perception than physics. I don't think you are going to find a very good answer. Light perception is not straight forward. People don't know everything about it. For example, there is red and dark red. There is green and dark green. There is yellow, but not dark yellow. Instead there is a different color, brown. Or see the [Checker shadow illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checker_shadow_illusion). A and B have the same brightness.

[image]

But I can guess at a reason. To begin, see this on [Fechner color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fechner_color). Your eye normally works with relatively steady light. Flickering lights are outside its normal envelope. They can fool the eye. In particular, receptors take time to turn on or off when suddenly exposed to light. Different color receptors have different time scales. While changing, you momentarily get more input from receptors from some colors and the light appears colored. For most of the cycle, the receptors are fully on or off, and you see white or black. But adding the bias from the momentary color gives an overall faint color under some circumstances, but not all.

Apply some of this idea to your case. Not the colors, but the idea that receptors have a latency when turning or or off. The on latency may be shorter than the off latency. If so, a brief bright flash will cause you to see a bright light, and what you see will have a longer duration than the pulse. This causes you to see a brighter light than you might expect.

This isn't really an explanation. It is more of a thought that this might be the direction to look for an explanation. It doesn't explain why light intensity matters, or why some flickers produce color and others don't.

Answer (score -2):

I'm no physicist but happened upon this when I noticed a similar phenomenon with my crt monitor. I decided to run it at 48hz instead of the usual higher refresh rates just to see what it would look like. Crazily enough, it looked brighter to my eyes. I talked to some other people about this who also still use crts and one said he noticed the same thing. He measured with a tool and said the nit measurement was the same with 48hz as the higher refresh rates. This leads me to believe that it indeed due to what you described. The black information between lines being drawn was long enough at 48hz to trigger my eye to adapt to a darker light condition and the next frame was then perceived as brighter due to my eye adapting. Something to note is that it must need to be significant flicker, as 72hz vs 48hz was a drastic difference and crts already have insanely low persistence.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).